# How do you get an element to fill out the rest of the space in a btn-group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get a Bootstrap btn-group to work, with a few fixed elements and a btn in the middle that grows to fill out the entire thing.

JSFiddle of what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2988/

Basically the idea is I'm trying to get the 3 and 4 buttons to stick to the right, while the "Text here" element fills out the rest of the space. Menu sticks to the left.

I've tried putting `btn-group-justified` on the element I want to expand out but that makes it take up the entire width of the screen, whereas I want everything to be on one line.

HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="First group" style="width:100%; margin-right:-300px"> 
    <div class="btn-group dropup" role="group"> 
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Menu <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu"> 
            <li><a href="#">Edit Lead</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Transfer Call</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="First group" style="width: 100%; margin-right:-320px">
        <span class="btn btn-default" style="width:100%;">
            Some text here
        </span>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">3</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">4</button>
</div>
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: nest the 3&4 divs inside a div and give it a class of `pull-right`, check http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats ,but check ur code first.

Comment: doesnt work. and also splits those 2 buttons apart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it.

Needed to set `table-layout:auto` on the parent group and add width:1% to the fixed size elements, width:100% to the expandable elements and add the class `btn-group-justify` to the parent group. Looks perfect now!

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/2996/

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="First group" style="table-layout:auto">
    <div class="btn-group dropup" role="group">
        <a type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            Menu
            <span class="caret"></span>
        </a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Edit Lead</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Transfer Call</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <span class="btn btn-default" style="width: 100%;">Hey there</span>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-default">3</a>
    <a type="button" class="btn btn-default">4</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Doesn't work because it doesn't fill the parent container horizontally.

Comment: u mean u want those btns to fill the 100% width ?

Comment: No, just the Some text here to be fluid and fill out the container horizontally, the size of the other buttons shouldn't change.

Comment: i found that the secret was in the `table-layout` so i edited the answer and it should work ,it does exactly the same as ur answer just with less markup.